# I am writting a program to change file location. But it does not work correctly

Tags: c, file

I debuged this many times. The program can create new file in new loation but the new file doesn't have content from the source file. The pointer s have no value. Please tell me why i got this problem and help me fix it.

So here is my function in source.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

        void changeFileLoc(char filename[],char location[])
    {
        char newname[255];
        sprintf(newname, "%s\\%s\0", location, filename);
        FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");   
        if (fp!=NULL)
        {
            char*s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeofFile(fp));
            FILE* f = fopen(newname, "wb");
            fread(s, sizeof(char)*sizeofFile(fp), 1, fp);
            fwrite(s, sizeof(char)*sizeofFile(fp), 1, f);
            fclose(fp);
            fclose(f);
            free(s);
        }   
    }
long sizeofFile(FILE *f)
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long kq = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);
    return kq;
}
```

Here is my main:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "Header.h"
void main()
{
    changeFileLoc("randombinary.txt", "D:\\Game");
    _getch();
}
```

This is my header:

```
 #ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

long sizeofFile(FILE *f);
int FileExist(char filename[]);
void changeFileLoc(char filename[], char location[]);

#endif
```

Comment: What's the definition of `sizeofFile`?  The problem is most likely there.  Also, you should check the return value of `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: Show us the `sizeofFile` function. And `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you can remove the `sizeof(char)*` multiplications.

Comment: i have showed the sizeofFile.

Comment: @Pablo Why it creates new file but can not add the content to the file?

Comment: @dbush I have tested this code and can not print the s. I think problem is my fread. Can you help me solve this?

<pre>
void changeFileLoc(char filename[],char location[])
{
 char newname[255];
 sprintf(newname, "%s\\%s\0", location, filename);
 FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
 if (fp != NULL)
 {
  char*s = (char*)malloc(sizeofFile(fp));
  fread(s, sizeofFile(fp), 1, fp);
  puts(s);
 }<code>

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't transfer the contents, it should. I advise you to check the return value of the `fread` and `fwrite` functions

Comment: @Pablo The problem is at fread. I read by fread(s,sizeof(s),1,f); but i can not print the s on screen.

Comment: what is the return value of `fread`? It should be 1.

Comment: @F.Wu I strongly suggest you (a) check the return value of every function (in this case fread and fwrite), and (b) implement some debugging tactics (such as the gdb debugger, valgrind, or other debugging utilities)

Comment: OT: `main()` returns `int` not `void`, BTW.

Comment: Check the malloc result too.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you should check out the [`CopyFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`MoveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: You state that the posted code is C++ but you are using C header files.

Comment: regarding: `#include <conio.h>`  The header file: `conio.h` is not portable.  Strongly suggest not using it.  Everything in `conio.h` can be performed via calls to C library functions

Comment: regarding: `__HEADER_H__`  in general, the C language reserves leading `<_><_>`  and `<_><capital letter>` for its' own use.  Suggest removing the leading underscores

Comment: BTW: the posted code is trying to COPY the file, not change its location

Comment: CHECK THE RETURN VALUES FROM YOUR IO CALLS (open, read etc). I apologize for shouting but this seems to be the only way to get your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though fragile, the code posted works on my machine.  That said, it should be made more robust with error checking.  Those checks would likely help you in quickly determining how it's going wrong in your case.  Some other best practices would also make the code easier to understand (and thus easier to debug).

First, be aware that the method you're using to determine the size of the file isn't guaranteed to be portable by the language standards--the value returned by `ftell` is really only useful for seeking.  That said, it will do the right thing on Linux.  It will also work on Windows *if* the file is opened in binary mode (as it is in your program).

Next, naming things more clearly will help avoid mistakes.  `fp` and `f` aren't very useful here.  Names like `source` and `target`, `src` and `dest`, or `oldfile` and `newfile` would go a long way to avoiding mistakes.  The variable `kq` seems to be meaningless unless it's an abbreviation for file size in some other language.  Even the name `changeFileLoc` is misleading; `copyFileToLoc` would be more appropriate.

The guts of `changeFileLoc` are confusing because all the operations are interleaved:  first it constructs the new file's name, then it opens the old file and creates a buffer to hold it, and then it opens the new file, then it reads the old file, then it writes to the new file.  It's pretty scrambled. And it results in unnecessarily overlapping variable lifetimes, which makes it easier to write bugs.

There's another principle called "don't repeat yourself," which is often abbreviated to DRY.  Things like computing the file size three times is not just inefficient, but it clutters the code, making it harder to see what's going on.  Computing it once and saving it to a well-named variable will make this easier to understand.

Additional clutter includes an unnecessary cast, surplus string termination, and multiplication by 1 (which wouldn't be so bad if it happened in just one place).

So let's apply these principles to the code:

```
// Returns the size of the file in bytes, or 0 if the size cannot
// be determined.
long sizeofFile(FILE *f) {
  if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  long size = ftell(f);
  rewind(f);
  return size;
}

void copyFileToLoc(char filename[], char location[]) {
  FILE *source = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (source != NULL) {
    size_t size = sizeofFile(source);
    char *s = malloc(size);
    if (s != NULL) {
      fread(s, 1, size, source);
      fclose(source);

      char newname[255];
      sprintf(newname, "%s\\%s", location, filename);

      FILE *target = fopen(newname, "wb");
      if (target != NULL) {
        fwrite(s, 1, size, target);
        fclose(target);
      }
      free(s);
    }
  }
}
```

This is better, but still not great.  We've checked for some errors but not others (e.g., `fread` or `fwrite` could fail).  Even so, we're already on our way to the arrow code anti-pattern (where the code gets heavily indented).  It might be worth decomposing into smaller functions.

Answer (score 0):

the posted code is opening a file for reading.

Then opening the SAME file for writing.

Suggest re-thinking the calls to `fopen()`

Also, any library function that you used (except `rewind()`) can fail. Strongly suggest adding the necessary code to ALWAYS check the returned values to look for errors